# Without using jquery I want a popup dialog box that gives choices to links

Tags: javascript

I am a noober and I don't want to learn jquery just yet.  I want an alert style popup dialog box with choices to go to two links, one or the other.  If any of you genius experienced obi-wan types could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very concise and easy way:

```
if (confirm("Go to Google?"))
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";

else if (confirm("Go to Bing?")) 
    window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";

else 
    alert("Not going anywhere");
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  I could use this.

Comment: @user3555228 Could you please use the accept button (the tick mark) to accept the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: I wound up just hiding a div and then unhiding it with javascript.

Comment: @user3555228 If you want help regarding anything, you can always use the "Ask a question" button.